# What should I pass to this Intent constructor inside an event listener?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, this

I am new to Android development and I am trying to start another activity when the user clicks on an item in a ListView. However, I am stuck trying to create an Intent to do it. I am trying to follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) guide, where they use the `this` keyword. However, it doesn't work in this case because `this` refers to the `AdapterView.onItemClickListener`.

My current code is this:

```java
list.setOnItemClickListener(
   new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                              View item, int pos, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
        // use the Intent to start another activity...
        }
   });
```

What should I be replacing `this` with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use your activity name before `this`, example:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
```